# Is a question that asks how to do something which would require a tutorial in an answer too broad or off topic?

Tags: discussion, flags, close-reasons

If someone asks a question that could only be answered with a tutorial, should the flag reason be because the question is "too broad", i.e. it has many possible answers which could be rather long; or because the question is off topic (the implication being that it asks for a recommendation of a tutorial)?

Comment: There *is* specifically a close reason for "asking for off-site material"... What's the confusion over using that?

Comment: Isn't the answer fairly obvious? There is an off-topic reason that covers this as you say in the question.

Comment: I meant asking for a tutorial given in an answer, like "how do I accomplish this"?  It's not specifically off-site

Comment: It depends on the scope of what a user is trying to accomplish... some questions are on topic, some too broad, some have many answers (and perhaps all answers are equally valid - a question can still be on topic in such a case).

Comment: One question I was reviewing asked "How do I create a database for a website with [some technology]?"

Comment: Point being "how do I accomplish X?" != "I need a tutorial on..."

Comment: Or "how do I set up push notifications?"

Comment: In such a case as you describe, there is no way to give a single, objectively correct answer. The OP needs to give more details (and constraints). This would normally fall under "too broad" or "unclear".

Comment: I think my edit clarifies what OP was asking.  The previous version was a no-brainer.  Consider removing your downvotes.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I meant.

Comment: @Will Even when the question has been clarified, it's still a rather silly question to ask.  "If someone asks a question that's too broad and not asking for a recommendation, should I close it for being too broad or for asking for a recommendation?"  It's a question that answers itself.

Comment: Did I ever state the the question in question was too broad?

Comment: @Servy Of all the silly questions I see daily here, this is the least of them. Yeah, it's obvious to most of us which one we'd choose or that it doesn't really matter, but I think asking for advice whether it should be treated as simply too broad or as an implicit request for a tutorial is fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It very specifically depends on the question. Some *"how can I approach this problem"* questions are perfectly reasonable and answerable in a paragraph or two. Others would indeed require writing a step-by-step tutorial covering many broad topics, which is clearly not what we're here for. Other questions may not have enough constraints to clearly arrive at *one* answer, which would also qualify it for being *"too broad"*.

You as a domain expert need to evaluate the question and judge whether it can reasonably be answered or would require handholding too extensive to be within the scope of SO.

Unless the OP specifically asks for an *offsite resource* ("can someone give me a link to a tutorial"), that close reason doesn't apply.

Comment: ... and even if it *does* apply, sometimes editing it into shape is easy enough, which might be preferable to closing.

Answer (score 4):

If they're explicitly requesting that someone provide them a link to an off-site tutorial, then close it with the "recommendation request" close reason. If it's not explicitly a resource request, but rather is simply so broad that one would have to essentially write a long-form tutorial, then close it as "too broad".

You'll just have to use your judgement to decide which of those two is the case.